# How does epoll return the correct file descriptor

Tags: c++, linux, network-programming, epoll

I have two UDP connections and I'm trying to add them to use `epoll()`. I am looking at this example:

https://programmer.ink/think/epoll-for-linux-programming.html

I've pasted the code below.

At the beginning they create an epoll event along with an array of epoll events:

`struct epoll_event ev,events[20];`

I'm not sure why both are needed.

They then call `epoll_wait()`:

`nfds=epoll_wait(epfd,events,20,500);`

and the socket is retrieved:

`if(events[i].data.fd==listenfd)`

However, `events` was not populated between these three lines.

1. So how does `events[i].data.fd` contain the socket file descriptor?
2. Why do we set `ev.data.fd=listenfd;` if we have an array of `epoll_event`, which has a file descriptor data member?

   ```
   struct epoll_event ev,events[20];
   //Generate epoll-specific file descriptors for processing accept s

   epfd=epoll_create(256);
   struct sockaddr_in clientaddr;
   struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
   listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   //Set socket to non-blocking

   //setnonblocking(listenfd);

   //Set the file descriptor associated with the event to be processed

   ev.data.fd=listenfd;
   //Set the type of event to process

   ev.events=EPOLLIN|EPOLLET;
   //ev.events=EPOLLIN;

   //Register epoll events

   epoll_ctl(epfd,EPOLL_CTL_ADD,listenfd,&ev);
   bzero(&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
   serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   char *local_addr="127.0.0.1";
   inet_aton(local_addr,&(serveraddr.sin_addr));//htons(portnumber);

   serveraddr.sin_port=htons(portnumber);
   bind(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
   listen(listenfd, LISTENQ);
   maxi = 0;
   for ( ; ; ) {
       //Waiting for the epoll event to occur

       nfds=epoll_wait(epfd,events,20,500);
       //Handle all events that occur

       for(i=0;i<nfds;++i)
       {
           if(events[i].data.fd==listenfd)//If a new SOCKET user is detected to be connected to a bound SOCKET port, establish a new connection.

           {
               connfd = accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&clientaddr, &clilen);
               if(connfd<0){
                   perror("connfd<0");
                   exit(1);
               }
               //setnonblocking(connfd);

               char *str = inet_ntoa(clientaddr.sin_addr);
               printf("accapt a connection from\n ");
               //Setting file descriptors for read operations

               ev.data.fd=connfd;
               //Set Read Action Events for Annotation

               ev.events=EPOLLIN|EPOLLET;
               //ev.events=EPOLLIN;

               //Register ev

               epoll_ctl(epfd,EPOLL_CTL_ADD,connfd,&ev);
           }
           else if(events[i].events&EPOLLIN)//If the user is already connected and receives data, read in.

           {
               printf("EPOLLIN\n");
               if ( (sockfd = events[i].data.fd) < 0)
                   continue;
               if ( (n = read(sockfd, line, MAXLINE)) < 0) {
                   if (errno == ECONNRESET) {
                       close(sockfd);
                       events[i].data.fd = -1;
                   } else
                       printf("readline error\n");
               } else if (n == 0) {
                   close(sockfd);
                   events[i].data.fd = -1;
               }
               if(n<MAXLINE-2)
                   line[n] = '\0';

               //Setting file descriptors for write operations

               ev.data.fd=sockfd;
               //Set Write Action Events for Annotation

               ev.events=EPOLLOUT|EPOLLET;
               //Modify the event to be handled on sockfd to EPOLLOUT

               //epoll_ctl(epfd,EPOLL_CTL_MOD,sockfd,&ev);

           }
           else if(events[i].events&EPOLLOUT) // If there is data to send

           {
               sockfd = events[i].data.fd;
               write(sockfd, line, n);
               //Setting file descriptors for read operations

               ev.data.fd=sockfd;
               //Set Read Action Events for Annotation

               ev.events=EPOLLIN|EPOLLET;
               //Modify the event to be processed on sockfd to EPOLIN

               epoll_ctl(epfd,EPOLL_CTL_MOD,sockfd,&ev);
           }
       }
   }
   return 0;
   ```

   }

Comment: The calls to `epoll_ctl()` add the FDs to poll to the polling FD.

Comment: @Barmar but `events` is not passed here?

Comment: `events` is passed to `epoll_wait()`. It fills it in.

Comment: `ev` is used when adding an event to wait for `epoll_ctl()`, `events` is the list of events that occurred.

Comment: Got it. If you put an answer i'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. So how does `events[i].data.fd` contain the socket file descriptor?

It's put in there by `epoll_wait()`. It fills in the `events` array with information about all the events that occurred.

> 2. Why do we set `ev.data.fd=listenfd;` if we have an array of `epoll_event`, which has a file descriptor data member?

`ev` is used to register events to wait for with `epoll_ctl()`, the `events` array contains the events that occurred.

Comment: Regarding the second question, if I'm listening to multiple sockets, i only need to set `ev.data.fd` with one of the sockets?

Comment: You call `epoll_ctl()` multiple times, to add each socket you want to monitor. That's why it calls it with `listenfd` at the beginning, and `connfd` after accepting each connection.